# How to copy parameters from global model to thread-specific model

Tags: python, tensorflow

#### Context:

I am new to TensorFlow and I'm trying to implement some of the algorithms in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01783v2.pdf) which require occasionally copying from a global shared model to local thread-specific model.

#### Question:

What is the best/correct way to accomplish the above task? I've provided a dummy example of the way I am currently doing this below and the error I'm getting. Can someone please explain why the error occurs?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import threading

class ExampleModel(object):
  def __init__(self, graph):
    with graph.as_default():
      self.w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1, shape=[1,2]))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
global_network = ExampleModel(graph)
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

def example(i):
  global global_network, graph
  local_network = ExampleModel(graph)
  sess.run(local_network.w.assign(global_network.w))

threads = []
for i in range(5):
  t = threading.Thread(target=example, args=(i,))
  threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
  t.start()
```

#### Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kennyhsu5/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/kennyhsu5/anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "tmp.py", line 16, in example
    local_network = ExampleModel(graph)
  File "tmp.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1, shape=[1,2]))
  File "/Users/kennyhsu5/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 211, in __init__
dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/kennyhsu5/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 319, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/Users/kennyhsu5/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2976, in __exit__
    self._graph._pop_control_dependencies_controller(self)
  File "/Users/kennyhsu5/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2996, in _pop_control_dependencies_controller
    assert self._control_dependencies_stack[-1] is controller
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 3):

About [tf.Graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Graph) class in Tensorflow:

> Important note: This class is not thread-safe for graph construction.
>   All operations should be created from a single thread, or external
>   synchronization must be provided. Unless otherwise specified, all
>   methods are not thread-safe.

The `self.w = ...` declaration and the `local_network.w.assign(...)` operation are causing the error.

I know it basically kills your multithreading implementation, but you can fix the above code by moving these declarations to the main thread. You can then use the threads to actually run what the operations you prescribed. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import threading

class ExampleModel(object):
  def __init__(self, graph):
    with graph.as_default():
      self.w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1, shape=[1,2]))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
global_network = ExampleModel(graph)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def example(sess, assign_w):
  sess.run(assign_w)

threads = []
for i in range(5):
  local_network = ExampleModel(graph)
  assign_w = local_network.w.assign(global_network.w)
  t = threading.Thread(target=example, args=(sess, assign_w))
  threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
  t.start()
```

I would also advice you to pass your variables to the thread via the `args` parameter rather than using `global`.

Finally, consider using `global_variables_initializer` instead of deprecated `initialize_all_variables`.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem regarding multithread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53611862/predicting-and-training-in-different-threads-keras-tensorflow?noredirect=1#comment94086593_53611862), is there any doc or examples that can guide me? Thanks!!