# Predicting and Training in different threads Keras Tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras and Tensorflow to make a kind-of online learning, where I receive new data periodically and I retrain my models with this new data. I can have several models stored in ".h5" files so that when i need to train or predict I load the model and then I perform the necessary operations.

Currently I separated the training and the predictions in two different threads, so that predictions can be made while the other thread trains. With locks I try to make sure that no prediction or training is done in the same model at the same time (I think this works), but I am aware that keras is not so prepared for this. I always some different errors regarding the graph or session of tensorflow, for instance:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 859, in predict_times
>       0] + '.h5')
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 164, in get_prediction
>       model, scaler = self.load_model_file(self.graph_pred, self.session, path)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 114, in load_model_file
>       model = load_model(path)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in load_model
>       model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 287, in _deserialize_model
>       K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2470, in batch_set_value
>       get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 206, in get_session
>       session.run(tf.variables_initializer(uninitialized_vars))
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 2831, in variables_initializer
>       return control_flow_ops.group(*[v.initializer for v in var_list], name=name)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3432, in group
>       return _GroupControlDeps(dev, deps, name=name)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3384, in _GroupControlDeps
>       return no_op(name=name)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in **exit**
>       next(self.gen)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4249, in device
>       self._device_function_stack.pop_obj()
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\traceable_stack.py", line 110, in pop_obj
>       return self._stack.pop().obj
>   IndexError: pop from empty list

Or the error:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 1182, in run
>       self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 632, in train
>       self.update_prediction_historics_all()
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 649, in update_prediction_historics_all
>       self.update_prediction_historics_dataset(new_dataset, loadModel=True)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 672, in update_prediction_historics_dataset
>       0] + ".h5", loadModel=loadModel)[
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 198, in get_predictions_sequential
>       model, scaler = self.load_model_file(self.graph_pred, self.session, path)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\PycharmProjects\ai-pred-eng\src\run_keras_server.py", line 114, in load_model_file
>       model = load_model(path)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in load_model
>       model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
>       model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
>       return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
>       printable_module_name='layer')
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
>       list(custom_objects.items())))
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 301, in from_config
>       model.add(layer)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 181, in add
>       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 431, in **call**
>       self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 872, in build
>       constraint=self.bias_constraint)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 252, in add_weight
>       constraint=constraint)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 402, in variable
>       v = tf.Variable(value, dtype=tf.as_dtype(dtype), name=name)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 183, in **call**
>       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 146, in _variable_v1_call
>       aggregation=aggregation)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 125, in 
>       previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2444, in default_variable_creator
>       expected_shape=expected_shape, import_scope=import_scope)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 187, in **call**
>       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).**call**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 1329, in **init**
>       constraint=constraint)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 1492, in _init_from_args
>       ops.add_to_collections(collections, self)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in **exit**
>       next(self.gen)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5347, in init_scope
>       yield
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4369, in **exit**
>       self._graph._pop_control_dependencies_controller(self)
>     File "C:\Users\a703572\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 4390, in _pop_control_dependencies_controller
>       assert self._control_dependencies_stack[-1] is controller
>   AssertionError

My solution was using a graph for prediction and a graph for training, and every time I want to perform a tf operation I use:

```
with server_predict.graph_pred.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=server_predict.graph_pred) as sess:
```

And I also added the line:

```
        backend.set_session(sess)
```

Despite this, I keep having the errors coming from the tf session or graph, as It seems that the operations are not properly separated. Another error is the one I wrote in this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3388) that is still opened, regarding the tf session. Solution given using k.clear_session() (k = keras backend) did not work for me.

Does any one have had a similar problem or has programmed a similar task that might help me?

Thanks!!

---

Found a "wrap" to make this work. Instead of launching two threads over the same class (custom), what I have is two objects of the same class, one is dedicated to training and the other to predict. This is not a real multithread app (even though the two objects are launched from the same main). Until I (we) find a proper multithread solution this might help.

However I do not understand know how I got the errors before, and just by having two objects not, even if these objects run in the same process. Is it that keras/tensorflow can only make operations on only one graph but defines different graphs for different objects on the same process?

Comment: Tough one... but it seems keras has only one graph, no matter how many models you have. Is it possible to have two keras instances, one in each thread?

Comment: are you actually asking me if that's posible or if I can program it? XD I dont know if it is possible to have two keras instances, do you know about this?

Comment: No, I don't... :( --- I don't really know much about threads, but if two different threads imported their own Keras and kept everything internal, maybe it would be feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to have two separate keras models - the first runs in inference mode, and the second runs in training mode. Every time the inference model gets a new dataset to predict on, it first checks to see if it has the most "up to date" `.h5` file, if not then it loads it in first then runs the prediction. This way you can avoid locks and such.

It's hard to give advice specific to your case because what you want is likely not the same as what I need

- This is my opinion after having done something similar with Tensorflow Multiprocessing

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you mean having two variables with two different models (training and pred), I do actually have that but the errors are coming when the operations on each model run at the same time (one in each thread). How did you separate the operations of each model in tf? Did you use a specific graph-session operations?